Send-MailMessage : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
I am trying to use aws ses service to send emails. But when I use this build-in function of powershell to send email it shows me this error. command that I am using is mentioned below.
Send-MailMessage -From $from_address -to $to -subject 'test subject' -Body $body -SmtpServer $smtp_server -Credential $credential -UseSsl -Port 25
and the error is:
Send-MailMessage : The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.
what could be wrong and what should be the next step.

Did you check the remote certificate?

Port 25 is not secure and doesn't use a certificate.  If you are inside a firewall port 25 could be correct and you do not need a certificate.  Otherwise change the port number.

Ses supports ports 25, 587, or 2587 25 is not secure. Also, have you considered using the AWS PowerShell module for SES - it will most likely take care of this for you?
